# Prolog. Remove from the first list items that have an even number of occurrences in the second list

Tags: prolog

I'm just starting to learn how to work with lists in prolog and I tried to make a program on the example of similar tasks, but it does not work.
The task is - **Remove from the first list items that have an even number of occurrences in the second list.**

I have such logic in this functions:

1. Function `counter` should return a Quantity of some element at the list.
2. Function `remove` ignore of elements which has even quantity at the second list.

My code:

```
counter(_,[],0).

counter(Number, [H|T], Quantity):- 
    Number =:= H,
    UpdatedQuantity is Quantity + 1,
    counter(Number, T, UpdatedQuantity).
    
counter(Number, [H|T], Quantity):- 
    Number =\= H,
    counter(Number, T, Quantity).


remove([], [], []).

remove([H1|T1], T2, [H1 | T1]) :-
    counter(H1, T2, Quantity),
    Quantity mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove(T1, T2, T1).
    
remove([H1|T1], T2, T1) :-
    counter(H1, T2, Quantity),
    Quantity mod 2 =\= 0,
    remove(T1, T2, T1).
```

For example, remove([1,2,3,4][1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,7], Res)
will return Res = [2,3,4,5,7,7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the second clause of predicate `counter/3` as follows:

- First find the solution to a simpler instance of the problem.
- Then use that solution to get the solution to the original instance of the problem.

```
counter(_, [], 0).

counter(Number, [H|T], UpdatedQuantity):-
    Number =:= H,
    counter(Number, T, Quantity),    
    UpdatedQuantity is Quantity + 1. 

counter(Number, [H|T], Quantity):-
    Number =\= H,
    counter(Number, T, Quantity).
```

Modify predicate `remove/3` as follows:

- Replace first clause with `remove([], _, [])`, since the second list doesn't need to be empty to stop the recursion.
- In the last two clauses, replace `T1` with `T3` (a fresh variable) when it appears in the third argument, since the resulting list may not be equal to the first input list.
- Also, swap the conditions used in the last two clauses; otherwise, you will remove items that have an *odd* number of occurrenes.

```
remove([], _, []).

remove([H1|T1], T2, [H1|T3]) :-
    counter(H1, T2, Quantity),
    Quantity mod 2 =\= 0,
    remove(T1, T2, T3).

remove([H1|T1], T2, T3) :-
    counter(H1, T2, Quantity),
    Quantity mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove(T1, T2, T3).
```

Example:

```
?- remove([1,2,3,4,5],[1,1,2,2,2,4], Res).
Res = [2, 4] ;
false.
```

**Improved solution** Avoid spurious choice points and redundant call of `counter/3`.

```
improved_counter([], _, 0).
improved_counter([H|T], Number, UpdatedQuantity):-
    improved_counter(T, Number, Quantity),
    (   Number =:= H
    ->  UpdatedQuantity is Quantity + 1
    ;   UpdatedQuantity is Quantity ).

improved_remove([], _, []).
improved_remove([H1|T1], T2, Res) :-
    improved_counter(T2, H1, Quantity), % solve this goal only once!
    (   Quantity mod 2 =:= 0
    ->  Res = T3
    ;   Res = [H1|T3] ),
    improved_remove(T1, T2, T3).
```

Example:

```
?- improved_remove([1,2,3,4,5],[1,1,2,2,2,4], Res).
Res = [2, 4].
```

Comment: thanks, it`s work fine. My mistakes look really stupid. Improved solution seems better but  a little difficult. Do I understand correctly that after symbol `->`  will be first case if condition is True and second if condition is false?

Comment: Yes! That works as `(Condition -> Then ; Else)` and it is recommended when `Condition` is a semi-deterministic goal (succeeds once or fail).